# Tomcat 6.0.23 and Eclipse Indigo - server not working through eclipse while working from standalone

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I'm  trying to load the server from eclipse it not really deploying it, it start quite fast (without exception).
while i start the same app through tomcat the server is up and it working fine.
any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,
Gal

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand ,the Apache Tomcat plugin supports up to [version 3.6 (Helios) of Eclipse](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html#A3) and not 3.7 (Indigo). Maybe I am wrong.